# Is parsing the only way to obtain the Member type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

The reflection code below returns:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[TestReflection.Car] Cars
```

How can I get the `Cars` root type through reflection? Not `IList<Car>` - how can I get `Car`?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestReflection
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type t = typeof(Dealer);
            MemberInfo[] mi = t.GetMember("Cars");

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", mi[0].ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Dealer
    {
        public IList<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Get the item type for a generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452590/c-sharp-get-the-item-type-for-a-generic-list)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way would be to produce a [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z852kf5.aspx) that represented the property in question and then its underlying type via [`PropertyInfo.PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx). Then it's just a matter of retrieving the type arguments for this generic type, for which you could use [**`Type.GetGenericArguments`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

```
Type carsElementType = typeof(Dealer)
                        .GetProperty("Cars") 
                        .PropertyType // typeof(IList<Car>)
                        .GetGenericArguments() // new[] { typeof(Car) }
                        .Single(); // typeof(Car)
```

Answer (score 1):

You take the Type object for a closed Type and then use GetGenericArguments that returns you the list of all types substituted for the generic parameters.

```
var l = new List<int>();
foreach(var genericArg in l.GetType().GetGenericArguments())
   Console.WriteLine(genericArg);  // returns Int32
```