# C# - Get the item type for a generic list

Tags: c#, collections, generics

What would be the best way of getting the type of items a generic list contains?  It's easy enough to grab the first item in the collection and call .GetType(), but I can't always be sure there will be an item in the collection.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Sonny

Comment: What do you know about the type already? Could you provide a sample context?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You could use the  [**`Type.GetGenericArguments`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method for this purpose.

```
List<Foo> myList = ...

Type myListElementType = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Comment: If the `T` token is in scope (say, in a method that accepts a `List<T>`), you could also use `typeof(T)`.  If the `List<T>` is stored in a variable of type `object` you will have to use the above approach.

Comment: Didn't you answer another question, almost exactly the same, earlier today?

Comment: @LukeH: Yes, lightning does strike twice :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448871/is-parsing-the-only-way-to-obtain-the-member-type/4448890#4448890

Comment: @Lambert: I'm not an expert on markdown, but I choose a block and click the "Code sample" icon. I suggest you click on the orange "?" at the top right-hand corner of the answer box to get more info on how this stuff works.

Answer (score 20):

For a more robust approach:

```
public static Type GetListType(object someList)
{
    if (someList == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("someList");

    var type = someList.GetType();

    if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(List<>))
        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be List<>, but was " + type.FullName, "someList");

    return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```

But if your variable is typed `List<T>` then you can just use `typeof(T)`.  For example:

```
public static Type GetListType<T>(List<T> someList)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Note that you don't really even need the `someList` parameter.  This method is just an example for how you could use `typeof` if you are already in a generic method.  You only need to use the reflection approach if you don't have access to the `T` token (the list is stored in a non-generic-typed variable, such as one typed `IList`, `object`, etc.).

Comment: Holy cow, nice error handling.  You might want to add localizable error text as well. ;)

Comment: Nice. A minor point - the arguments passed to new ArgumentException are the wrong way round.

Answer (score 13):

```
list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way which works for non-generic collections, too:

```
static Type GetItemType(Type collectionType)
{
    return collectionType.GetMethod("get_Item").ReturnType;
}
```

That is, get the return type of `foo[x]`, where `foo` is of the specified type.

Examples:

```
// Generic type; prints System.Int32
Console.WriteLine(GetItemType(typeof(List<int>)));

// Non-generic type; prints System.String
Console.WriteLine(GetItemType(typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection)));
```

---

The `GetItemType` method above has a couple issues, though:

- It throws a `NullReferenceException` if the type has no indexing operator.
- It throws an `AmbiguousMatchException` if the type has multiple overloads for the indexing operator (e.g. `this[string]` and `this[int]`).

Here is a more refined version:

```
public static Type GetItemType(this Type collectionType)
{
    var types =
        (from method in collectionType.GetMethods()
         where method.Name == "get_Item"
         select method.ReturnType
        ).Distinct().ToArray();
    if (types.Length == 0)
        return null;
    if (types.Length != 1)
        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} has multiple item types", collectionType.FullName));
    return types[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this, its all static (e.g. no instances required), and fast (no loops, no usage of linq), and it is simple :) these work for collections:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    public static Type GetIndexedType(this ICollection poICollection)
    {
        PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo = poICollection == null ? null : poICollection.GetType().GetProperty("Item");
        return oPropertyInfo == null ? null : oPropertyInfo.PropertyType;
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    public static Type GetEnumeratedType(this ICollection poICollection)
    {
        PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo = poICollection == null ? null : poICollection.GetType().GetMethod("GetEnumerator").ReturnType.GetProperty("Current");
        return oPropertyInfo == null ? null : oPropertyInfo.PropertyType;
    }
```

And a few simple unit tests:

```
        [Test]
        public void GetIndexedType()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(null, ((ICollection)null).GetIndexedType());
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(int), (new List<int>()).GetIndexedType());
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(bool), (new SortedList<string, bool>()).GetIndexedType());
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetEnumeratedType()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(null, ((ICollection)null).GetEnumeratedType());
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(int), (new List<int>()).GetEnumeratedType());
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(KeyValuePair<string, bool>), (new SortedList<string, bool>()).GetEnumeratedType());
        }
```

Notice the fact that there are two ways to look at this, one type may be returned by the indexer and an other type may be returned by the enumerator. The unit test do show both.

Have fun,
Frans.

P.s. For enumerables:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    public static Type GetEnumeratedType(this System.Collections.IEnumerable poIEnumerable)
    {
        PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo = poIEnumerable == null ? null : poIEnumerable.GetType().GetMethod("GetEnumerator").ReturnType.GetProperty("Current");
        return oPropertyInfo == null ? null : oPropertyInfo.PropertyType;
    }
```

And for enumerator:

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    public static Type GetEnumeratedType(this System.Collections.IEnumerator poIEnumerator)
    {
        PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo = poIEnumerator == null ? null : poIEnumerator.GetType().GetProperty("Current");
        return oPropertyInfo == null ? null : oPropertyInfo.PropertyType;
    }
```

Comment: Here your methods accept the non-generic versions of each interface, but will only work as intended if they in fact implement the generic versions.  If you're going to have those requirements, you may as well just have the methods accept generic versions of the interfaces directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public Type GetType(IEnumerable<object> resultList)
    {
        return resultList.GetType().GetElementType();
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

Old question new method with `dynamic`

```
void Foo(){
   Type type GetTypeT(data as dynamic);
}

private static Type GetTypeT<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that also works with derived classes.

Because with this class :

```
  public class SubList : List<int>
  {   }
```

If you call  : `subList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single()`

It will throws a **System.InvalidOperationException**

With this method it works for derived classes :

```
public Type GetListItemType<T>(List<T> list)
{
  Type type = list.GetType();
  while (type != typeof(List<T>))
    type = type.BaseType;
  return type.GetGenericArguments().Single();
}


var list = new List<int>();
var subList = new SubList();
Console.WriteLine(GetListItemType(list)); // System.Int32
Console.WriteLine(GetListItemType(subList)); // System.Int32
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Public Shared Function ListItemType(ListType As System.Type) As System.Type

  If Not ListType.IsGenericType Then
    If ListType.BaseType IsNot Nothing AndAlso ListType.BaseType.IsGenericType Then
      Return ListItemType(ListType.BaseType)
    End If
  Else
    Return ListType.GetGenericArguments.Single
  End If
End Function
```