# How to determine if an unknown type is a List<T> and what type T is

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to extract the type of an unknown property and determine if it is a `List<T>`, and if `T` is of a specific type.

I understand how to use reflection to determine the type of a property, however I cannot figure out how to determine if a property is a `List<T>` and what type `T` is. Hope you guys can help.

Edit: [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt) is not quite applicable. The answers there assume I know that my unknown type is a `List` to begin with. I have edited my title to be more clear.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.generictypeparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CompuChip You might want to expand on that comment a little. Perhaps show demo code in an answer, so that the OP has an idea of what to do.

Comment: also `list.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single()` from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4452598/4767498

Comment: My title was not clear, I do not even know if the type is a list to begin with. I have edit my question and title appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object o = new List<double>();

Type t = o.GetType();

if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    Console.WriteLine("This is a list of type {0}", t.GenericTypeArguments[0].Name);
```

Comment: This throws an exception if `o` is not a generic type. Is there a way to check if it's a generic type to avoid having to rely on an exception to determine that it is not a generic type?

Comment: yes, see the updated answer

Comment: Ah! I did not know about `IsGenericType` thank you!