# Item type from a list type c#

Tags: c#, list, types

I have a Type variable that's List of some type. Supposing I don't know the item type, how do I get the item type?

Something like

```
...
var type = property.PropertyType;

if (type == typeof(List<>) // I know this doesn't work
{ do something }
...
```

EDIT: I even tried `type is Ilist` and `type.IsGenericType`, and are both results are false.

Even simply trying with

```
var a = (new List<int>()).GetType(); 

if ( a.IsGenericType && a is IList){} //  both conditions return false
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, but neither works for me.

Comment: var itemType = type.GetElementType(); results in null

Comment: whats wrong with .GetType()?

Comment: `GetType() or typeof` do a google search on it there are lots of examples on `Stackoverflow, MSDN, and Google`

Comment: if its a List<string> he want to get string

Comment: `Type itemType = type.GenericTypeArguments.First();`

Comment: @Don'tmindme first of all I would suggest editing your question and updating it with the actual code that you're trying to `GetType()` of.. you show one thing in the question but comment showing something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Get the item type for a generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452590/c-sharp-get-the-item-type-for-a-generic-list)

Comment: @KevinBourassa-Houle I don't have an instances of the list, I have a type that is List (int in this case)

Comment: @MethodMan Actually all i have is the type variable. which I get byreflection with property.PropertyType. It's what is next which I don't have

Comment: @RomanKoliada my friend, I think this is working. Testing right now

Comment: Do you want to check whether your type is generic List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding you want to check if the type is a list and if the list's elements is type X.

You can do the following:

```
        var type = (new List<int>()).GetType();

        if (type.GetInterface("IList") != null && type.IsGenericType
                && type.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1
                && type.GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(int))
                    Console.WriteLine(true); //Outputs True
```

Comment: Exactly. I tried that , `type is Ilist` and `type.IsGenericType`, and are both results are false. Even simply trying with `var a = (new List<int>()).GetType();` and asking for `a.IsGenericType` and `a is IList` result in false. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `type.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1` and `type.GenericTypeArguments[0] == typeof(int))` are true tho...

Comment: @Don'tmindme updated and tested.