# get item type of an Eloquent collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I am trying to find the best way to retrieve the Eloquent Model type of items in a collection.

Of course I can get the first item and ask for its type, but it's likely that I hit an empty collection and there's no other way to get the type then. 
This question is similar to this one here 
[C# - Get the item type for a generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452590/c-sharp-get-the-item-type-for-a-generic-list) 
but I couldn't find any addressing this for laravel or php.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function on the Collection called `getQueueableClass()` that will return the type of the items in the collection. The function basically does a `get_class($collection->first())` but it takes care of asking if the collection is empty before. But, as you can see in the source code if there are objects with different types on the collection it will throw an exception.

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Collection.php#L392

Comment: This brings bad news, I skimmed through the code and I don't think there's an answer for what I want ! This method though basically returns null if the collection is empty which is not what I wanted. This collection can be declared like this $users = App\Users::all(), I need to know the type even if empty

Comment: These collections don't work like the ones in C# or Java where you have to declare what type of data you'll be storing. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can achieve what I am trying to accomplish in other ways but I won't be following a CLEAN architecture that way .. It's okay though I'll manage. I thought there might be way to do like c#

Comment: The get_class() function returns stdClass which is not sufficiently informative.