# How to get type of objects in an empty list of an interface

Tags: c#, list, reflection, interface

Consider:

```cs
public interface I
{
    int InterfaceProperty {get;set;}
}

public class C1 : I
{
    public int InterfaceProperty {get;set;}
    public int Class1Property {get;set;}
}

public class C2 : I
{
    public int InterfaceProperty {get;set;}
    public int Class2Property {get;set;}
}

//In some other class:
public List<I> L;
void somemethod()
{
    this.L = new List<I>();
    this.L.Add(new C1());   //add some C1s into the list
    SomeMethodToGetProperties(L);
    this.L = new List<I>();
    this.L.Add(new C2());  //add some C2s into the list
    SomeMethodToGetProperties(L);
}
```

I need SomeMethodToGetProperties that gets a list of the properties for C1 or C2. ie, first call returns InterfaceProperty and Class1Property and the second call returns InterfaceProperty and Class2Property.

I can't use an object in the list, because the lists may be empty. I tried Reflection on the lists, but that only gave me the properties for the interface.

EDIT: The original way I wrote it was not valid. You can't do

```
this.L = new List<C1>()
```

You can only do something like

```
this.L = new List<I>();
this.L.Add(new C1());
```

It seems what I need may not be possible from the metadata of the list itself.
So I created a second variable to hold the type of item held in the list that I set every time I change the list contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452590/c-sharp-get-the-item-type-for-a-generic-list

Comment: the solution to that question only returns the interface properties.

Unless I a missed a specific comment or other link you were referring to?

Comment: Show us how you tried with reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one implementation, that scans each item in a list, and collects the item type and its properties. This is because each list might have more than one type that is inherited from the interface.

<sub>**I renamed the interface and classes for clarity**.</sub>

The result is

```
Class1
        InterfaceProperty
        Class1Property

Class2
        InterfaceProperty
        Class2Property
```

with code:

```
public interface IInterface
{
    int InterfaceProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : IInterface
{
    public int InterfaceProperty { get; set; }
    public int Class1Property { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 : IInterface
{
    public int InterfaceProperty { get; set; }
    public int Class2Property { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static List<IInterface> list;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list = new List<IInterface>();
        list.Add(new Class1());
        list.Add(new Class2());
        list.Add(new Class1());
        list.Add(new Class1());
        list.Add(new Class2());

        foreach (var itemType in GetItemTypeProperties(list))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itemType.Key.Name);
            foreach (var property in itemType.Single())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{property.Name}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type,PropertyInfo[]>> GetItemTypeProperties<T>(List<T> list)
    {            
        var itemProperties = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var t = item.GetType();
            if (!itemProperties.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                itemProperties[t] = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            }
        }
        return itemProperties.GroupBy(kv => kv.Key, kv=>kv.Value);
    }
}
```

---

You can also get the same result, by scanning only the first item in the list and assuming the remaining items are of the same time. This time, like in your question, I re-assign the list with a new set of items of a different type.

This produces the following result:

```
Class1
        InterfaceProperty
        Class1Property
Class2
        InterfaceProperty
        Class2Property
```

from the code:

```
        list = new List<IInterface>();
        list.Add(new Class1());
        list.Add(new Class1());
        list.Add(new Class1());

        var item1 = list.First();
        var properties1 = item1.GetType().GetProperties();
        Console.WriteLine($"{item1.GetType().Name}");
        foreach (var prop in properties1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{prop.Name}");
        }

        list = new List<IInterface>();
        list.Add(new Class2());
        list.Add(new Class2());

        var item2 = list.First();
        var properties2 = item2.GetType().GetProperties();
        Console.WriteLine($"{item2.GetType().Name}");
        foreach (var prop in properties2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{prop.Name}");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the actual type of the list:

```
Type listType = this.L.GetType();
```

To get the types of objects it can contain:

```
Type elementType = listType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

To get the properties for that type:

```
var properties = elementType.GetProperties();
```

Comment: That is what I was trying. It is only returning the interface properties.

Comment: @JamesDePaola I missed your edit where the object is actually a `new List<I>();`. In that case yes you'll only get the interface properties. If you added a `C1` and looked at the properties of items in the list you would get them. So perhaps look at the interface properties if the list is empty, otherwise look at the first item? I don't know what your full use case is to know what the full answer is.