# Getting type of List<object> that is empty

Tags: c#, list, casting

```
List<SomeClass> classObject = new List<SomeClass>();
someClass = .....
classObject.Add(someClass);

// For some reason we need to cast this List to List<object>.
List<object> objectList = classObject.Cast<object>().ToList();

// The receiving end will try then cast the item using the items in the objectList
var newInstance = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(objectList[index].GetType().FullName);
```

**All works except if the list is empty,** the receiving ends are unable to cast new instance without knowing the fullname of the intended instance.

Is there anyway around it without passing the Type of someClass?

I have tried GetGenericArguments but failed as it returns System.Object which we can't use.

Comment: there is no check in place to see if the list is empty before trying to access its items?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say "no", there isn't a way. Your list is one of type `object`, which without containing an instance of `someClass` could potentially contain more or less anything. How should the compiler know what type you intended to, or once kept in your list?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The sample above is after they check if the list is not empty performed by another extension class. The problem we are trying to solve here is finding a way to get type of object without object in the list. We do know that there is only one type of object in list.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Hi Geroge, we thought the same too as its already an base object and there is no workaround. Guess we have to pass the type as well in this case but that is really a lot of refactoring to do. We have an extension class that converts class to datatable, list, xml, model and so on. All parts can work well except for this issue with list as we are unable to build the correct datatable with an empty list. :(

Comment: If the list is empty, what's the purpose of trying to create an object out of an onexsiting item from the list? Aren't you getting an exception when you try to access item from empty list by doing `objectList[index]` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The purpose is to construct a datatable dynamically using the type(someClass) from a list that was previously casted from someClass. Do not worry about the objectList[0], we know what will happen and we handle that too. We are trying to get type from List<object> if its empty. We could have missed out some solution since it was originally casted from List<someClass> to List<object>. We can also pass the type instead which can a workaround for us but its really too much code to refactor. The question is "If there anyway around it without passing the Type of someClass?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452590/c-sharp-get-the-item-type-for-a-generic-list check this [Example Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FrI2hp) it uses the same approach of GetGenericArguments but with one difference. It does not do `ToList` when Casting.

Comment: Does the receiving end use the exact same instance of the `List<object>`?

Comment: @Knoop Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a warning that I consider this a "hacky" solution, however you ask for a way so here it is.

The problem is that a `List<object>` doesn't hold the information we need. If there are items in the list you can work around this by checking the item, but this obviously doesn't work if there are no items in the list.

So we need to create a way to add the information we need to the `List<object>` we can do that by creating our own `List<object>`:

```
public class MyTypedObjectList : List<object>
{
    public MyTypedObjectList(Type type)
    {
        MyType = type;
    }
    public Type MyType { get; }
}
```

And for ease of use we can create an extension method to do the creation for us:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static MyTypedObjectList ToMyTypedObjectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var myTypedObjectList = new MyTypedObjectList(typeof(T));
        myTypedObjectList.AddRange(source.Cast<object>());
        return myTypedObjectList;
    }
}
```

Now we can do:

```
List<object> objectList = classObject.ToMyTypedObjectList();
```

And use it as a `List<object>` all through the rest of the code.

Then in the receiving end (since we're using the same instance) we can cast back and get the type even if the list is empty:

```
var myTypedObjectList = (MyTypedObjectList) objectList;
```

And finally do this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(myTypedObjectList.MyType.FullName);
```

As said this is a hacky way, but if you really wanted to this should solve your problem (but please consider refactoring and solving this the right way)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, hacky but works. Since the current source code (which i believe) cast every fking List<T> to List<object> before the custom extension, now a quick search and replace plus 4 blocks of codes will do!